# How to write python script on linux to run a specific command requiring two files, which have similar file names

Tags: python

I am struggling for creating python script in Linux terminal. I am trying to make command to analyze hundreds of files.

And there is a python program(`ngCGH`) which analyze `bam.file`. `ngCGH`'s command is following:

```
ngCGH -o /mnt/data/A/B/C.txt [normal.bam] [tumor.bam]
```

Two `.bam` files have following naming role

```
1N-------.bam
1T-------.bam

2N-------.bam
2T-------.bam
```

In short, files having matched number should be analyzed.

In addition, I want to make output file name differently like in following way.

```
1N------.bam 1T------.bam
Result: 1NT analysis.txt

2N------.bam 2T------.bam
Result: 2NT analysis.txt
```

The output files should be txt files having different names.

Comment: Why do you want this in Python rather than a shell script or makefile?

Comment: Hi Ignacio. It is not a problem if I can run the analysis program for hundereds files. The program is python based program. So, I tried to make python bash file to run program in Linux.

Comment: A program can't be both Python and bash; you will have to make up your mind.

Comment: You can run a linux command in python with os.system("commad") if it is what you're expecting

Comment: Actually, I recently started programming. So , I have little knowledge on programming and its terminology. But, I think that you can know what is my point.

Comment: When you ask StackOverflow to write your code for you, you usually get what you pay for. This question is not a question.

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
j = 1
files = set(x[2:len(x)-4] for x in os.listdir() if x.endswith('.bam'))

for i in files:
    command = 'ngCGH -o <path>/'+str(j)+'NT analysis.txt '+str(j)+'N'+i+'.bam '+str(j)+'T'+i+'.bam'
    os.system(command)
```

replace `<path>` with actual path.

Hope this was what you were expecting.

Comment: Thank you for your kind advice.